# Display chart data based on API call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, chart.js

i'm trying to learn react along with using store. What im trying to do is having 2 components (one main and child) I want to call API for data in main component and pass this data to child component and then render this data in react-chartjs-2 component.

This is my main component (Home.tsx) which calls API for UserData (I receive data from back-end properly as array [].

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { History } from "history";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { ApplicationState } from "../../store";
import { actionCreators, reducer } from "../../store/auth";
import axios from 'axios';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import { Card, Button } from 'antd';
import BalanceChart from "./child-components/BalanceChart";

type HomeProps = ReturnType<typeof reducer>
    & typeof actionCreators
    & { readonly history: History };

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({
                                         id,
                                         historicalBalanceValues
                                     }) => {
    const [balanceValue, setBalanceValue] = React.useState([]);

    const getUserRequest = async () => {
        let response = await axios({
            url: `https://localhost:44340/api/users/${id}`,
            method: 'get'
        });
        return response.data;
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        id = sessionStorage.getItem("userId");
        getUserRequest()
            .then(data => {
                setBalanceValue(data.item.balanceValue);

                if (!!data.item.historicalBalances){
                    historicalBalanceValues = data.item.historicalBalances.map(r => r.balanceValue);
                }
            });
    });
    return (
        <div >
            <h1 className='home-header'>Savings</h1>
            <div className='card-container'>
                <Card style={{ width: 400, marginLeft: '75px' }} title={'Total balance'}>
                    <div className='balance-container'>
                        <div className='balance-value'>{balanceValue}</div>
                        <Button className='goal-button' type='primary' shape='round'>Add goal</Button>
                    </div>
                </Card>
                <Card style={{ width: 400, marginLeft: '75px'}} title={'Balance trend'}>
                    <BalanceChart chartData={historicalBalanceValues}></BalanceChart>
                </Card>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
    id: state.auth.id
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Home);
```

And this is my second component in which I want to display Line Chart using data I have passed from Home component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import axios from 'axios';
import PasswordInput from "../../Login/child-components/PasswordInput";

type BalanceChartState = {
    balanceChartData: []
}
let chartOptionsData = {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Label',
        data: this.props.chartData,
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
};

export class BalanceChart extends Component<{chartData: any}, BalanceChartState> {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({balanceChartData: this.props.chartData})
    }

    render() {
        const { balanceChartData } = this.state;
        return (balanceChartData && balanceChartData.length) ?
         <Line data={chartOptionsData}></Line> :  <Line data={[0]}></Line>
    }
}

export default BalanceChart;
```

The problem is that data I'm passing from one component to the other one is 'undefined'. I think that API call for data happens after the components are rendered, however I don't know how can I achieve this. I want to pass data once components are rendered. I would like to know what is a good practice to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Your API call is `asyn`, so your child component will be rendered with initial value of data. You have 2 options, either you can conditionally render your child component if it has the data from API call or in your child component, check for data, if `null`, return `<></>`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, so I have added a conditional rendering to parent (Home) component. Render looks now like this:

```
<Card style={{ width: 400, marginLeft: '75px'}} title={'Balance trend'}>
{
   !!historicalBalanceValues ?
   <BalanceChart chartData={historicalBalanceValues}></BalanceChart> : <Spin/>
}
</Card>
```

So now I have infinite preloader (historicalBalanceValues is undefined), and even tough API call returns me an array with values it does not render my BalanceChart component. I think that conditional rendering is checked only once somehow. How can I achieve this to react on changes?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution and I did change both components to class components. I pass data between them using props and I use State to store data I have from back-end inside Home component. Thanks for help!